# Save a string as an image file

Tags: c#

I am making a winRar type aplication, and it is all working, except for one thing. You cannot open image files after they have been unpacked from my program. This is because they are not in binary mode. Everything else works, I just dont know how to transform a file into binery mode. In perl it was
open OUT
binmode OUT
and I thought it would be relativly simple for c# as well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no "binary mode" or "text mode" in a .NET stream.  You might want to show the code that's failing.

Comment: How about showing your existing code...?

Comment: @Aaronaught: While that's technically true, it's certainly possible that he's using a `StreamWriter`, which uses particular text encodings.

Comment: @Adam: That would be a problem with his code, then, not with the file. I certainly *hope* he's not using the string overloads of the `StreamWriter` for file compression... otherwise, "pack" is a synonym for "destroy."

Comment: @Aaron, oh, definitely a problem with his code. But the fact that the subject says "Save a string as an image file", I'm guessing that's exactly what he's doing.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as binary mode - if your file isn't opening after it's unpacked, it's because the data is not the same as it was going in.  Run a diff between the original and unpacked files, and you'll see that they're not the same.

If your app works properly, then every single byte will be identical, then you'll have no problem opening the unpacked file.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good luck with your project - building your own compression application is no small task - if you're doing this for a real world app, there are plenty of open-source solutions already built, that would probably suit your needs.  But if you're doing it for fun, then enjoy.